# What is a bitmask and a mask?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitmask

On the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) about JSON it mentions the word bitmask. Wikipedia has it defined as a mask. I don't understand either bitmask or mask or how they are useful. Can some one explain these terms using layman's terms and no jargon?